# Why did a crash at 100% battery cause instant drain to zero?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, battery, crashes

After charging my Galaxy SII (ICS) overnight, I unplugged and started using the web browser. Battery indicated 100%. After 20 minutes the screen went black and the phone rebooted, then it popped up a battery low warning. On plugging back in, it seemed to charge normally for a while and then jumped from 80 to 100% almost instantly.

I would post a screenshot of the battery screen but don't have enough reputation - it shows charge starting at 100%, dropping slowly for 20 mins, then instantly down to <10%. From there I plug in and it goes slowly up to 80%, then instantly up to 100% again.

Anyone fancy having a guess at what is going on here?

Comment: Are you rooted?

Comment: Until you can post screenshots, you can upload them to some image hoster and include a link here. Somebody with enough rep then can decide to convert that.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that the battery calibration data got lost. Probably through the crash.

Comment: Should that really matter? I always thought that file (`batterystats.bin` AFAIR) only holds data about which app cunsumed how much. Isn't the current charge of the battery decided via its voltage?

Comment: The voltage and charging current depends from battery to batterylevel. Therefore Android needs some calibration information to display the battery percentage.